# JDB -connect IO.Execption with no message

Tags: java, jdb

I have a java app running on a server (linux) whose ip is 10.7.185.168:8123, using this command.

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:8123 OurApplication
```

and I try to debug it from another machine (windows) with:

```
jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:hostname=10.7.185.168,port=8123 -dbgtrace 0x00ffffff
```

but this results in the following stacktrace

```
java.io.IOException
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.createVirtualMachine(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:238)
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.createVirtualMachine(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:245)
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.GenericAttachingConnector.attach(GenericAttachingConnector.java:120)
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketAttachingConnector.attach(SocketAttachingConnector.java:83)
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.attachTarget(VMConnection.java:519)
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.open(VMConnection.java:328)
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Env.init(Env.java:63)
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.TTY.main(TTY.java:1087)
```

I've seen reference to IO exception in other threads talking about failed handshakes but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

- I can ping the linux server and even connect to a "nc -l" request with Curl so I dont think its a firewall issue.
- if I netstat -tulpna | grep 8123 on the server it says that a connection was ESTABLISHED, but obviously it didn't make it back to me.
- Both my local machine and the server are running JDK 11.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow up to this question. I discovered with my team that a firewall TCP rule seemed to be the culprit. Simply put, the TCP packets for java debugging were **too large** and were automatically getting intercepted by my company's firewall. Packets for pinging and connecting via NC unix command were small enough to connect with no issue. I eventually settled on an alternative means to debug my code.